# is it possible to create symbolic links on exfat filesystem?

Tags: filesystem, symbolic-link, chmod

I cannot even change permissions with `chmod 777` that on one hand returns no error but on the other does not change the permissions either.

File system is exfat.

But my issue is inabililty to create symbolic links on exfat filesystem.
Have checked the [wiki entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT) for exfat but nothing caught my attention regarding the symbolic link, so the question is, does exfat by design allow for symbolic links?

[image]

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. It was done purely for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No** (copied from [Superuser.com: Does or will exFAT support symlinks?](https://superuser.com/questions/232257/does-or-will-exfat-support-symlinks)):

> Soft links:
>
> - NTFS  Yes
> - UDF   Yes
> - exFAT No
> - FAT32 No
>
> [Reference: File System Functionality Comparison](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/filesystem-functionality-comparison)

Comment: As I have commented below, prefer NTFS over UDF. UDF has no support to fsck (udffsck, not yet implemented). In practice, this means that the disk will be to write once and read-only file system. Roughly, a DVD/CD.  Bad for USB and HD format. Prefer NTFS for that purpose instead.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Microsoft filesystems do not follow POSIX rules.

--

edit:

UDF does support symbolic links (soft links) so you might want to switch to that.

Comment: Do not change to UDF. UDF has no support to fsck (udffsck, not yet implemented). In practice, this means that the disk will be to write once and read-only file system. Bad for USB and HD format. Prefer NTFS for that purpose.

Comment: The source code for udffsck is misleading (https://github.com/pali/udftools/blob/master/udffsck/main.c). It makes us to believe that the program actually does something, but it doesn't. Well... if you have a weird distro that uses https://github.com/argorain/udftools/tree/master/udffsck repo, there you are fine, but outdated relative to the official one. On debian, the repo used is the official one, then I believe that the same happens on all debian-based. To test it, check with 

"apt-cache show  udftools."

Answer (score 1):

the answer would appear to be slightly more nuanced

if you don't believe it i can provide screenshots, or try yourselves

```
Shodan:Documents gt$ mount |grep WD
/dev/disk4s1 on /Volumes/WD (exfat, local, nodev, nosuid, noowners)
Shodan:Documents gt$ cd /Volumes/WD
Shodan:WD gt$ ls >textfile
Shodan:WD gt$ ln -s textfile softlink
Shodan:WD gt$ ln textfile hardlink
ln: hardlink: Operation not supported
Shodan:WD gt$ file -h textfile softlink
textfile: ASCII text
softlink: symbolic link to textfile
Shodan:WD gt$ uname -a
Darwin Shodan 21.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 21.6.0: Thu Sep 29 20:13:56 PDT 2022; root:xnu-8020.240.7~1/RELEASE_ARM64_T6000 arm64
Shodan:WD gt$
```